# android.view.WindowLeaked on VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am facing errors "android.view.WindowLeaked" on using VideoView in android.
When i run my app videoview not run gives message "Video Can not be played" and logcat gives "android.view.WindowLeaked" error

Comment: you are trying to play file from sdcard or from  server?

Comment: i put the .3gp file in my raw folder of res

Comment: and i am plying the video on 7inch samsung tab

Comment: i was also see some other posts related to this issue on samsung tab. i'm also search for solution if found then inform u

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K thanks for the help. are you facing the same problem??
 i also finding the solution also and also waiting for any solution on my that question.